# Migrate android code error on eclipse

Tags: android

I have been working on a project and it was running error free. However, when I copied the files to another project, it showed error and as a fix eclipse suggested "Migrate android code". But it didn't work .in the logcat there is no error and on pointing at an error it saya '--- cannot be resolved'. i have been working fine with the project and project was running successfully. But when i copied this to other system also same error happened.  Please suggest a fix for this

Comment: More error details or stacktrace would be helpful. Just error doesn't help. As well as please improve your accept ratio.

Comment: Check the package ,jar files,buildpath,java compiler,properties correctly .

Comment: go to properties settings of project, if you can see that library android X.X(what you have defined 2.2,2.1,etc.) check that is it added or not, if not then select and android SDK target from properties

Comment: in the logcat there is no error and on pointing at an error it saya '--- cannot be resolved'. i have been working fine with the project and project was running successfully. But when i copied this to other system also same error happened.

Comment: can you be more precise and detailed please.

Comment: Try cleaning your project in Eclipse. Go to Project->Clean...

Answer (score 2):

Go into project.properties

If there is `android.library=true` then delete it. That should work.